# Free/Open source Application Skinning Solutions for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What are the open source alternatives available for skinning/Theming an application in .Net 
Winforms

I've read about using UXTheme library (i have no idea as to how to to da that :) ), but is that valid for Win XP to Win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at Krypton toolkit ? 
Seems to have some nice Winforms styles.

https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

It is not FOSS but it is no-cost.

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look at it.
But is it a freeware or a share ware styled license, the site is not clear, its says free and also has a buy button

Comment: The suite is commercial but the toolkit part is free.

Answer (score 0):

I think WPF beats pretty much each and every skinning/theming solution hands down (see [this](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx?id=catalog) for a for-pay, but impressive sample of what can be done).

Comment: Although I completely agree with you, you're not answering the question at all ;)

Comment: @Anton Gogolev thanks, but is there no way to do that in winforms, because i have an application in Winforms and i cant afford to suddenly change it to WPF.